# Output buffer pass from RegQueryValueExw to NtQueryValueKey

Tags: c++, c, winapi, ntdll

Upon calling of `RegQueryValueExW(...,output_buffer,size)` `NtQueryValueKey(...,KEY_VALUE_INFORMATION_CLASS, PVOID KeyValueInformation, ... )` is called and after that `memmove(output_buffer,src,size)` is called.

It says that `KeyValueInformation` is output for `NtQueryValueKey` How is information from `KeyValueInformation` is passed to `src`, since they are not the same pointer?

Comment: `RegQueryValueExW` call `ZwQueryValueKey` with `KeyValuePartialInformation` and output is [`KEY_VALUE_PARTIAL_INFORMATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ns-wdm-_key_value_partial_information)  - look for `Data` member

Comment: @RbMm something like `memcpy((PVOID)((PKEY_VALUE_PARTIAL_INFORMATION) &KeyValueInformation)->Data, data_from_registry, lenght);` happens?

Comment: only in reverse order data copyed from Data not to Data

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.